# Sharing a global variable between forked processes

Tags: c, process, fork

I have a global variable, X.  I then fork and modify X from the child.  I want those changes to show up in the parent, but I don't want the parent to have to wait on the child.

How can I do this?

Comment: You're probably better off threading here (and if you knew me, you'd know how much it hurt to say that), since you want multiple execution contexts to be able to modify data in a single memory instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the variable in shared memory.  There are many ways to create shared memory.  I'd probably just use `mmap`, but you could also check out `shmget` or `shm_open`.

Answer (score 1):

When you fork a new process that is a separate copy of the address space. It can only see the changes made *before* the fork.

If you want shared memory for communication between the processes, you have to create that explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, my question must be unclear.  I realize that they each get a separate copy and I'm trying to get around that and share a variable.  As in, how do I share memory between the processes?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

After forking, those are two separate processes.
You will have to make use of some [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: My question is asking about how to make use of some IPC.